# Can one reset Xcode 5's code completion? It's out of control

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode5, code-completion

Is there any way to reset code completion in Xcode 5? There is a similar question [here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12515241/reset-fix-xcode-4-5-code-completion) where the answer is to delete the ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserInfo, but that folder no longer exists. There is a folder called UserData but it contains stuff I'd rather not trash.
The problem is that from the moment I installed Xcode 5, its code completion is overzealous, offering lists of far-fetched, useless and even wrong suggestions. For instance, following this instantiation:

```
CALayer *imageLayer = [CALayer layer];
```

typing on the next line: "imageLayer. " brings up the following list of suggestions:

- Class class      (this is the highlighted suggestion)
- NSArray * classFallbacksForKeyedArchiver
- Class classForCoder
- Class classForKeyedArchiver
- Class classForKeyedUnArchiver

At wilder moments I've even seen search terms I'd googled with Safari and my own surname pop up. I had hoped that code completion would improve (I'm running Xcode 5.0.2 on 10.9.1), but even after months of use (and two weeks into Mavericks) the ridiculousness persists. Anyone else have this problem?

Comment: how about turning code completion ***off***?

Comment: This has happened to me before. Is there a syntax error/warning/no method found higher up in the file?

Comment: @Linuxios Hmm, thinking back, it may well be that the worst acting out occurs when there are syntax errors higher up.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann It had occurred to me (not sure it's even possible), but I like code completion. In Xcode 4 it was getting quite good, so I had high hopes for Xcode 5. It's a real shame Xcode 5 is such a step back, code completion and documentation navigation both.