# Code completion in Xcode 5 - not working for "for" and "switch" statements

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode5

In Xcode 4 when I start typing `for` it suggests two types of for loops, in Xcode 5 it suggests `fork()` function and thats it.

Same happens with `switch` statement, it doesn't detect it all.

What's wrong and how do I return old behaviour?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. But the suggestions depend on the file type (.m, .c, ...) What file type do you have?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12515241/reset-fix-xcode-4-5-code-completion Possible fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you clean your project ( cmd+shift+k), build it (cmd + b) and relaunch Xcode. Seems primitive but sometimes it helps me when the completion helper is a little off.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes XCode seems to loose track of the code completion data. Restarting xcode will usually fix the issue.